# Using JQuery to remove blank rows from HTML Tables

Tags: jquery, html, .net, html-table, asp.net-mvc-2

I have an HTML table:

```
<table id="indicationResults" class="resultsGrid" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" >
```

Some of the cells in the table only contain strings depending on specific permissions. For example, here is one row that only puts a label and data in each cell if the user has a specific permission:

```
<tr>
    <td id="DV01Label" class="resultsCell">
        <%= CustomHelpers.StringWithPermission("DV01", new string[] { PERMISSIONS.hasALM })%>
    </td>
    <td id="DV01Value" class="alignRight">
        <%= CustomHelpers.StringWithPermission(Model.Results.DV01.ToString(Chatham.Web.Data.Constants.Format.CurrencyCentsIncludedFormatString), new string[] { PERMISSIONS.hasALM })%>
    </td>
    <td id="DV01Fixed" class="alignRight">
        <%= CustomHelpers.StringWithPermission(Model.Results.FixedComponent().DV01.ToString(Chatham.Web.Data.Constants.Format.CurrencyCentsIncludedFormatString), new string[] {PERMISSIONS.hasALM})%>
    </td>
    <td id="DV01Floating" class="alignRight">
        <%= CustomHelpers.StringWithPermission(Model.Results.FloatingComponent().DV01.ToString(Chatham.Web.Data.Constants.Format.CurrencyCentsIncludedFormatString), new string[] { PERMISSIONS.hasALM })%>
    </td>
</tr>
```

How do I go back through and delete and all completely empty rows in this SPECIFIC table after the page loads using JQuery, so instead of seeing a tiny little empty row, it's just not there.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With jQuery:

```
$('#indicationResults tr').each(function () {
     if (!$.trim($(this).text())) $(this).remove();
});
```

Although it would be much better if you could modify your asp to only output rows when the user has the right permissions ;)

Comment: Treat the problem, before the cure as they say :)

Comment: +1 for the comment on fixing the problem server-side. This should not be a JavaScript solution.

Comment: That modification will happen if it kills me, lol. Gotta way until next sprint though =/

Answer (score 0):

You should write a proper HTML helper. Contrary to web forms, MVC gives you full control over the generated HTML and is totally inexcusable to use javascript to fix broken HTML.

So:

```
public static MvcHtmlString RowWithPermission(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, 
    string cssClass, 
    string id, 
    string value, 
    string[] permissions
)
{
    if (HasPermissions(permissions))
    {
        var td = new TagBuilder("td");
        td.AddCssClass(cssClass);
        td.GenerateId(id);
        td.InnerHtml = value;
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(td.ToString());
    }
    return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
}
```

and then:

```
<tr>
    <%= Html.RowWithPermission("resultsCell", "DV01Label", "DV01", new string[] { PERMISSIONS.hasALM }) %>
    <%= Html.RowWithPermission("alignRight", "DV01Value", Model.Results.DV01.ToString(Chatham.Web.Data.Constants.Format.CurrencyCentsIncludedFormatString), new string[] { PERMISSIONS.hasALM }) %>
    ...
</tr>
```