# htmlTable removal of empty rows and columns

Tags: c#, dataset, rows, html-table, multiple-columns

I've been trying to find a way to remove all the empty rows and columns from my htmlTable. Is there a way to convert the htmlTable into a DataSet, remove the emptys rows and columns and then convert it back to a htmlTable? Can this be accomplished without converting it to a DataSet? I'm pretty sure I'll have to iterate through the entire table and the rows/columns, but beyond that I'm lost. I will still need the final output to remain as a htmlTable as this information is being displayed within a asp form.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have empty rows? Are you sending those empty items to the client? Is a user deleting specific rows or something? I'd like to see more info about your set up but, to me, it seems pointless to do this server side. Unless it's possible to not send those empty items to the client I'd use jQuery to do the removal client side. See [Using JQuery to remove blank rows from HTML Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760583/using-jquery-to-remove-blank-rows-from-html-tables) about doing this with javascript / jQuery.

Comment: I tried the jQuery approach but the blank rows and columns are still showing up in the table.

Comment: Then you had to have been doing something wrong. If you give me some more information I can offer more help. How do you end up with the empty rows / columns? Are they being deleted client side or are you sending out empty rows from the server?